# Magento 2.3 keep product / catalog image original size

Tags: magento2.3.1, image-quality

When I upload a product image that is for example 2400px * 2400 px in admin. Magento automatically compress it to 1200px * 1200px. Is it possible to tell Magento not to compress my images?

When searching on google, some articles say in Magento 2.3, it is possible to config image quality in admin, but I couldn't find such settings in admin.

I'm using Magento 2.3.1

---

update:
I have looked in the view.xml, I can find image sizes for thumbnails etc,  but I can't find any values like 1200px.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set image sizes in `view.xml` file inside your theme
Find the code where it is setting image size to 1200x1200 and change it with your desired one.

Code would be something like this:

```
<view xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/view.xsd">
    <media>
        <images module="Magento_Catalog">
            <image id="bundled_product_customization_page" type="thumbnail">
                <width>140</width>
                <height>140</height>
            </image>
            <image id="cart_cross_sell_products" type="thumbnail">
                <width>200</width>
                <height>248</height>
            </image>
            <image id="cart_page_product_thumbnail" type="small_image">
                <width>165</width>
                <height>165</height>
            </image>
            ........
        </images>
    </media>
    ......
</view>
```

Make sure your all images sizes are 1:1 ratio, as your main image proportion is 1:1 in ratio, than after frontend deployment it should work

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

Comment: I've looked at the view.xml. I did found the different image sizes, like thumbnail and small_image etc. but I can't find anything like 1200px.

Comment: Then it would be setting in parent theme